# exploding particles

Tags: physics

trying desperately to prepare a short animation of the inside of a cell.   I want to show little proteins bouncing around inside the membrane.  I have 3 problems, I will post all 3 separately because it seems those are the rules.  I've also uploaded the blender session below.

problem #1:  I have my particles contained within a box constructed from 6 planes(front and back walls are transparent so I can see inside).  Walls and proteins have 1.0 bounciness.  I used solidify on all the walls.  When I run the animation EVERYTHING EXPLODES and flies through the walls out of the box.  Any suggestions appreciated.

[image]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/upw5904htbfry0s/Phospholipids_and_brownian_motion.blend/file

Comment: some ideas: could enable 'Split Impulse' in Rigid Body World to avoid the 'explosion' but making them smaller as Chris said should be enough here; you could use the Lock on Y for each object if you want a 2D simulation and delete 2 walls but lay objects on a plane first; reduce friction to zero; maybe add some turbulence for a few frames or set initial velocity to some objects via keyframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (physics) simulations you should always apply your scale. -> CTRL-A -> scale

[image]

You shouldn't ever use negative scales.

If you use "Sphere" as shape object, Blender uses your object as exact that sphere.

[image]

So your "spheres" are overlapping as you can see and this isn't possible in the "real" world so either they have to deform or something else bad will happen...which you can see as your "explosion".

So either you make them all smaller so they don't overlap or move them.

result after making them smaller:

[image]

Comment: this helped.  thank you so much.

Comment: Please check the checkmark left of my answer, if it helped. Thank you.